# How to use node v0.10.5 runtime for Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: node.js, ide, cloud9-ide

I have installed Cloud9 IDE with node v0.6.19. 
The default node installed is v0.11.5.

When I start a simple script with Cloud9 (with node v0.6.19) it uses the version of node I started Cloud9 IDE (v0.6.19).

```
console.log('Version: ' + process.version);
```

logs `v0.6.19`

Is there a way I can use different version of node? I want to use v0.11.5 for my application and v0.6.19 for Cloud9 IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Cloud9 IDE on [https://c9.io/](https://c9.io). I too wanted to change the version of Node and found this page, but none of the instructions helped. I'm posting my solution for future Googler's.

Cloud9 has the `nvm` node version manager pre-installed. These are the steps I used to change the version of Node that runs when you click "Run" for a file.

```
$ mkdir /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions
$ nvm install 0.12.0
$ nvm alias default 0.12.0
```

Why the mkdir? Probably because the [nvm support is "rudimentary"](https://docs.c9.io/writing_nodejs_hello_world.html#nvm-support). Anyway, that's what worked for me.

You can confirm this by adding this to your `server.js` file:

```
console.log("Node Version: " + process.version)
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Cloud9 IDE latest master branch (`fbedf05b23`) with Node.js v0.10.17.
You need libxml2 installed. I'm using Mac OSX.

```
brew update
brew install --universal libxml2
brew upgrade node
git clone https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git
cd cloud9
npm install
npm install jsDAV
sudo bin/cloud9.sh -w ~/path/to/workspace --username xxx --password xxx
```

Comment: I did try your suggestions. However, Cloud9 crashes when tried with v0.10.5 and v0.10.17. 
Here is the console copy-paste when it crashes:
events.js:69
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:887:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:678:34)
    at process._makeCallback (node.js:299:20)

Comment: The output you provided is useless. You may post what you did and btw which system and version do you use.

Answer (score 0):

Open tun panel (running figure near setting button) and pick required version from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The trick seems to be to edit `/cloud9/configs/default.js` and specify

```
{
    packagePath: "./cloud9.run.node",   // or "./cloud9.run.node-debug"
    listenHint: "Important: in your scripts, use 'process.env.PORT' as port and '0.0.0.0' as host.",
    // **** ADD THIS: ****
    nodeVersions: {
        "0.10": "/root/.nvm/v0.10.21/bin/node"
        // and so on...
    }
},
```

for the plugins `cloud9.run.node` and `cloud9.run.node-debug`.

Comment: That directory doesn't some to be available.